# Checked Out A Scratch Org In VS Code and Want to Go Back

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I was connected to my production org with VS Code and checked out a scratch org through my VS Code. Now I want to go back to my production code but am not sure what commands to go back to the "master" branch. I am hoping I didn't overwrite my production org....any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two main concepts you need to be concerned about: your git repository branch, and your Connected Org.

The Git repository is a local copy of your code, and you can track modifications to your metadata, and share them on a remote Git server (e.g. GitHub). The state of this local workspace, as well as the remote workspace, isn't automatically the state of your Connected Org, whatever that may be.

The Connected Org is where you're currently pushing your code/configuration to. Each org you create is independent of each other, so a Scratch Org is not the same as your Production Org. Changes to one do not automatically affect the other, or your local or remote Git repositories.

You can determine both of these on the status bar, as highlighted in this screenshot:

[image: VS Code with Git and a Connected Org]

The `master*` (lower-left) in the screenshot shows I am on the master branch, with modifications. The `sfdcfox` indicated to the right of that shows that I am connected to my Developer Edition org.

To change the branch, click on the branch icon, and select a new branch to move to. To change to a different Connected Org, click on the plug icon, and select a new Connected Org to connect to.

Note that deployment to a Production Org is blocked by default, in order to prevent accidents like what you're worried about from happening. It's not "impossible" for this to happen, of course, but the default settings make it unlikely. There's no setting to turn on tests in VS Code extensions, as far as I'm aware, so you have to go out of your way with a terminal command to deploy to a Production Org.

You can check if you've made any deployments to production by logging in to production and clicking on Setup > Environments > Deploy > Deployment Status, and checking for any recent deployments. You can click on one to see the included components, status, and any errors.

If nothing is listed here, you have not deployed to your Production Org. Otherwise, if you need to make a deployment, you'll need to use the Branch (lower-left icon in screenshot) and the Connected Org (Plug icon to the right of the Branch icon in screenshot) to get to the correct branch and/or Connected Org, then run a relevant deploy command, such as:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -w 100 -l RunLocalTests
```

Note that this command may take significant time, depending on how many tests you have. The terminal will appear unresponsive during that time, which is normal (you can run this as a background task, but that's for another day).

If you have any more specific questions, please let me know, but this amount of detail should be enough to get you started with understanding your current state of affairs and how to proceed with some basic tasks.

Comment: thank you @sfdcfox!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem here... Scratch org and Production org have the same credentials, so VsCode grouped them... Now anytime I create a new proyect, authorize org and try to get the production codes, I can't, it just gets the scratch orgs. I think I made the mistake of making it the default org in my VsCode, but can't remove it because "You can't remove a DevHub org"... Any ideas?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/184037)